# How can I save form data to a different filename for each submission?

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that emails data and saves it into a file, but I want it to save to a different file each time.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    // Contact Form

    // get posted data into local variables
    $EmailFrom = "gmail.com";
    $EmailTo = "mail@gmail.com";
    $Subject = "$Website";
    $Website = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Website'])); 
    $Title = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Title'])); 
    $Keywords = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Keywords'])); 

    // validation
    $validationOK=true;
    if (!$validationOK) {
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
      exit;
    }

    // prepare email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Website: ";
    $Body .= $Website;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Title: ";
    $Body .= $Title;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Keywords: ";
    $Body .= $Keywords;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email 
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
        $string = '"Website","Title","Keywords"' . PHP_EOL;
        $string .= "\"$Website\",\"$Title\",\"$Keywords\"" . PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents('formdata.txt', $string); // write file
        print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=ok.html\">";
    }

    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to suggest databaseing your information, otherwise you're going to have to use timestamp information and/or random numbers or guid's to generate unique file names.

Comment: I'm more interested in having these report files in a folder so I can browse and download them when I need to. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that uses the current time:

```
file_put_contents('formdata_' . time() . '.txt', $string); // write file
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply however this doesn’t seem to work and actually it does not save the file and does not send the email anymore..

Comment: @Jack_R: Since this line happens after the email is sent, I would have to say that something else is wrong.

Comment: You right it was a different variable, this work just like I needed, Thank you.

Comment: I changed the order of the form so file is created filrst and then sends the result by email, how can I attach the file to the email? as it name is changing every second.. 
I tried using , $fileatt = $file ; but no luck